# can native window contents be replicated on html5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, window, native

Is it possible to replicate native window's content in a HTML5 Canvas in similar ways as the html5-based remote desktop applications work?

If the native window and the browser are running on the same computer, would there be notable lag in drawing the contents?

Comment: You would like to capture a window (not the browser) and display that in canvas, right? I'm afraid you can't do that, at least not without some browser plugin that would do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Well like I said, without a plugin you are out of luck ... sorry